# Magento2 Configure varnish-6.4.0 in magento2.3.2

Tags: magento2

How to config varnish-6.4.0 in Magento2.3.2?

I need to install varnish cache in my system, but the version of varnish cache installed is varnish-6.4.0. How can I Config it?

Answer (score 0):

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html

**To configure Magento to use Varnish:**

Log in to the Magento Admin as an administrator.

Click `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full Page Cache`.

Comment: I followed the steps but doesn't seem to go well with version 6

Comment: Have u tried same with varnish version 6?

Answer (score 0):

Just got the answer Varnish 6 was started in Magento2.3.3 & I am using 2.3.2 so need to install Varnish 5